# Is there a CSS way to solve hover over touch device?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there any new progress on solving hover issues using css for touch devices? I know last post was around 2016.. I am hoping for some new development using css to solve the hover issue over touch media.
Please advice any method using css.

I have tried using .dropdown:active but cannot click on it when drop down list.

```
.dropbtn {
  background-color: black;
  color: black;
  border: none;
}


.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);

}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

 <div class="dropdown">
            <p><a>Sample Drop Down</a></p>
               <div class="dropdown-content">
                 <p><a href="click1.html">Click1&#169</a></p>
                 <p><a href="click2.html">Click2&#169</a></p>
                 <p><a href="click3.html">Click3&#169</a></p>
               </div>
             </div>
```

Comment: Eleborate on ' hover issues'?

Comment: Hover does not work on touch screen device? Assuming the website is meant for both desktop and mobile devices.

Comment: You have no mouse pointer on touch devices so hover is not really a thing there. In some cases you could see a hover activated element on click but that's more a flicker

Answer (score 0):

Hover class needs a pointing device (a pen device), because which is distinguish the action pointing and selecting. On mobile device which has a touch interface you don't have this former.

Read this article:
https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#dynamic-pseudo-classes

Comment: I know thats why i am seeking advice how to solve this using any need css method if any?